# App Testing Strange

Tags: testing

I obtained my apple certificate, and my application ran on my iPhone 3gs(5.0.1), but on this application aren't applied recent changes; if i build the application on iOS 5.0 simulator, the application apply this recent changes, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your build in Xcode! This way it will be updated. The application can be cleaned by press in command-shift-k. You can also find it under Product -> Clean.

Comment: I just did a clean but i have the same result, it's too strange

Comment: Sometimes the processes are hang in the stack.

Comment: Also try deleting the app from your device.